# A memory leak in cvCaptureFromCAM?

Tags: c++, debugging, video, memory-leaks, opencv

It turns out that using cvCaptureFromCAM creates a memory in initialization. Usage of cvCaptureFromCAM creates a 48 byte memory leak of a NSAutoreleasePool object. I initially thought my program had a bug, but when replaced with a much simpler program, the memory leak still occurs.

For example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
   IplImage *frame = 0;
   CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM (-1); //leak occurs on this line  
   //using 0 instead of -1 creates a leak too

   cvNamedWindow ("Output", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

   while (1)
   {
      frame = cvQueryFrame (capture);
      cvShowImage ("Output", frame);
   }

   cvDestroyAllWindows ();
   cvReleaseCapture (&capture);

   return 0;
}
```

I am using Xcode Leaks to find memory leaks and am obviously using the Xcode IDE on Mac OS X 10.6. Does anyone know a solution to the leak? Am I doing something wrong or it a bug in OpenCV or a problem with my computer? I double checked my code and the OpenCV code but couldn't really find a problem. The memory leak is a one time thing - it doesn't keep building. However I am not comfortable with leaving ANY leaks in my program. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unfortunately unable to find the leak in cvCaptureFromCAM, so I switched to the C++ interface and used a VideoCapture object, which appears to be free of leaks.

Comment: Interesting that switching to C++ fixed it for you. I've been using OpenCV 2.4.2, and the C++ interface and have finally traced a memory leak of NSAutoreleasePool to my call to `cameraPtr = new cv::VideoCapture(0)`

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is this part

```
while (1)
{
   frame = cvQueryFrame (capture);
   cvShowImage ("Output", frame);
}
```

in my idea you have to change this unlimited  WHILE to FOR and 
for have to be fix memory size and after for you have to use

```
Release();
 or 
EndQuery();
```

i do this method like this

```
 while (1)
 {
  for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
  {
      frame = cvQueryFrame (capture);
      cvShowImage ("Output", frame);
  }
  Release();
  EndQuery();
 }
```

Comment: The problem isn't with retrieving frames, but with initializing the camera. Even if I remove the whole loop part, and just leave the camera initialization, I still get a leak. This leads me to believe there's not a bug in my code, but instead one in the OpenCV library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the memory leaks with `cv::VideoCapture` and `NSAutoreleasePool`.   The problems are all in `modules/highgui/src/cap_qtkit.mm`.

I found about 3 examples of the following:

1. An `NSAutoreleasePool` is allocated.
2. A method exited early (this code very liberally uses early returns out of functions)
3. Some of these returns do not clean up after themselves when using an early `return`

So the fix is for every occurrence of `[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]`, check the remainder of the function for a `return`.  If there isn't a statement along the lines of `[localpool drain]`  (or whatever variable name was used in the alloc) just prior to the `return`, then add one in.

There are 2 other source files in highgui that use `NSAutoreleasePool` that may have similar issues, but I don't use them and haven't checked.

Once I fixed this issue, my memory leaks went away.  Again, I'm using OpenCV 2.4.2.